# Как сделать UPSERT - обновить или вставить запись в таблицу?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Есть таблица:

```
monitored_tablespaces (
    tablespace_name       PK not null, 
    component_type        not null, 
    fqdn                  not null, 
    inventory_name)
```

Необходимо в ОДНОМ запросе, либо добавлять новую таблицу в список по `tablespace_name`, либо, если такое имя таблицы уже есть, обновлять в ней данные.

Пробовал с `MERGE`, но пока не понимаю реализации.

Comment: [MERGE Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9017.htm#SQLRF01606)

Comment: Пробовал, пока не понимаю реализации.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё очень просто. Источник записей помещается в `USING`. Если найдётся в целевой таблице запись по условию в `ON`, то она обновится, в противном случае - добавится новая запись.

```
create table item  (
    name varchar2 (16) primary key, 
    type varchar2 (8) not null, 
    memo varchar2 (32))
/    
merge into item t using (
    select 
        'name1' name, 'type1' type, 'memo1' memo
    from dual) s on (s.name = t.name)
when matched then update set t.memo = 'updated '||s.memo
when not matched then insert values (s.name, s.type, s.memo)
/
```

Выпонив два раза вышеуказанный запрос, посмотрите, как меняется результат:

```
NAME     TYPE     MEMO                            
-------- -------- --------------------------------
name1    type1    memo1                           

NAME     TYPE     MEMO                            
-------- -------- --------------------------------
name1    type1    updated memo1
```

Если осталось что-то непонятным, измените подготовленный [фиддле](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c8fcf4244a86762c4ed7d4d5e33231bd) и оставте комментарий с обновлённой ссылкой.

Comment: Спасибо тебе, добрый человек!!!!))))